# Create csv from inconsistent text file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I have loosely structured records in a file consisting of either 3 or 4 lines of text separated (mostly) by a blank line. Not all records have a blank line separator, but the last line of each starts with the word "Added". I would like to produce a csv file with each record on one line preceded by its line number. So far I have only been able to produce a concatenation of all records separated by an arbitrary number of spaces and a redundant comma.

Logically I am trying to achieve the following:

> Read line, if line starts 'Added' keep newline at end
>      else replace 'newline' with ','
>      or if line is blank delete it
>   endif

Sample data:

```
Peter Green  
Space Monkey at Area 51  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago  
Will Rossiter  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago

Dean Matthews  
Guitarist at Blues  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago  
Hobbit Mak  
Farnborough, United Kingdom  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago  

Keneth W Moorfield  
THE STOREMAN  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago  
Mick Georgious  
Software Engineer  
Joined  
Added by SF 3 weeks ago
```

Comment: You haven't said how big your data is. I'd be tempted to slurp it into `emacs`, and manually regularize the format to make later parsing easier.

Comment: The dataset is thousands of  records - which is why I gave up on manual editing @waltinator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/./{ printf "%s%s", $0, (/Added/?"\n":",") }' data
```

Using your sample input data:

```
$ awk '/./{printf "%s%s",$0,(/Added/?"\n":",")}' data
Peter Green,Space Monkey at Area 51,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
Will Rossiter,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
Dean Matthews,Guitarist at Blues,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
Hobbit Mak,Farnborough, United Kingdom,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
Keneth W Moorfield,THE STOREMAN,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
Mick Georgious,Software Engineer,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
```

How it works:

- `/./{...}`

  This performs the commands in curly braces only if the line contains a character.  In other words, this ignores blank lines.
- `printf "%s%s",$0,(/Added/?"\n":",")`

  This prints the line, denoted `$0`, followed by either a comma or a newline depending on whether the line matches the regex `Added`.

Comment: I know "It's easy when you know how" but that was startlingly quick and looks effective. I am humbled and grateful. Thank you @John1024.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `sed` solution (with `awk` do do the line numbering):

```
$ sed -n -e :a -e '$!{/^$/!N}; /,Added/ {P;D}; s/\n/,/; ta' data | awk '{print NR","$0}'
1,Peter Green,Space Monkey at Area 51,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
2,Will Rossiter,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
3,Dean Matthews,Guitarist at Blues,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
4,Hobbit Mak,Farnborough, United Kingdom,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
5,Keneth W Moorfield,THE STOREMAN,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
6,Mick Georgious,Software Engineer,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
```

Basically we just keep appending non-empty lines of input and replacing their newlines with commas, except we check at each iteration to see if we have a whole record and if we do, spit it out i.e.

- set a program label `:a`
- if not at the end of file `$!` then append non-empty lines to the pattern space `{/^$/!N}`
- if we are at the end of a record `/,Added/` then print it `P` and delete it `D` from the pattern space
- substitute comma for newline `s/,/\n/`, branching back to `a` on success

Comment: RTFM RTFM  Head down and researching how you have used sed - impressive, thank you @steeldriver

Comment: @SeniorMoments thanks - I like to explore its dusty corners ;)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here's a `perl` option:

```
$ perl -lne '
    push @rec, $_ unless /^$/; if (/^Added/) {print join ",", ++$n, @rec; undef @rec;}
' data
1,Peter Green,Space Monkey at Area 51,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
2,Will Rossiter,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
3,Dean Matthews,Guitarist at Blues,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
4,Hobbit Mak,Farnborough, United Kingdom,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
5,Keneth W Moorfield,THE STOREMAN,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
6,Mick Georgious,Software Engineer,Joined,Added by SF 3 weeks ago
```